# Broken link in url of mailto body

Tags: html, outlook, hyperlink, mailto

I need to send emails with a url link in the body.
we work with outlook 365 and the url gets broken where it hits a number.

for this html:

```
<a href="mailto:test@gmail.com?subject=test&body=http%3A%2F%2Fmytestsrv%2Findex.html">send email</a>
```

this is the result:

[image]

but for this html:

```html
<a href="mailto:test@gmail.com?subject=test&body=http%3A%2F%2Fmytestsrv01%2Findex.html">send email</a>
```

this is the result:

[image]

I tried to open the html from chrome and edge. same result.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in GMAIL Nor sending that gmail to outlook

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for your comment. but i need to make it work in OUTLOOK 365.

Comment: Have you got a solution to this?

Comment: nope sorry.....